# Examine a folder named `-F/`

Tags: bash, ls, cd-command

I think this folder was probably created by accident at some point, but I can't `ls` or `cd` to it to check.

Things I have tried:

```
ls '-F'

ls "-F"

ls \-F

ls \\\-F

ls \\-F
```

and the `cd` equivalents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always specify the file as absolute or relative path instead of just the file name.

The simplest way is to just prefix it with a `./` to indicate it's in your current directory and avoid having the first character of the argument being a `-` that causes it to be treated as option/flag:

```
ls ./-F
```

This should work with basically every command that expects a file name or path as argument, even those which do not support the use of `--` as argument separator.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
ls -lah -- -F
```

The `--` denotes the end of options for the command, same will work with `cd` and even `rm`.

```
cd -- -F
```

and

```
rm -r -- -F
```